# Filed to conecction to MySQL at localhost:3306 with user root

Tags: mysql, windows, mysql-workbench, localhost, connection

En Windows he instalado MySQL Workbench version: 8.0.31 y estoy creando una conecction pero me salta ese error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿y ya tienes instalado el servidor mysql en tu windows y está activo y a la escucha en dicho puerto 3306?

Comment: Como puedo saber lo del puerto. En principio esta instalado.

Comment: Si está instalado y no has tocado nada de la configuración, y está activado, entonces tiene que estar a la escucha en el puerto por defecto, el 3306.  Desde linux te diria que hiceiras un `telnet localhost 3306` pero en windows tengo mis dudas que dispongas de ese comando por defecto.

Comment: No, no he tocado nada de la configuración. Lo he desistalado e instalado 2 veces y nada.

Comment: En windows poco te puedo ayudar, la verdad, no lo toco ni lo uso, ni tengo ninguno disponible, ni ganas :-)  Supongo que si buscas algun tutorial sobre como instalar MySQL en windows te pondrá que en algun momento si que debes ir a configurarlo editando alguno de sus archivos de configuración, cosa que ya has dicho que no has tocado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instalar la versión correcta para hacer uso de mysql en Windows https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/